# Why directories are not being expanded and some others are not created?

Tags: bash-scripting, sh

I am using Docker and I am trying to run the following script in the container which uses Alpine Linux and sh as a shell:

> Note: `SCANDISK_MOUNT` and `SCAN_MOUNT` are environment variables defined as `var/scanserver` and `/var/scan`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -z "$SCANDISK_MOUNT" ]] && [[ -z "$SCAN_MOUNT" ]]; then
  return 0;
fi

for i in folder1 folder2 folder3 folder4; do
  if [ -d "$SCANDISK_MOUNT/$i" ]; then
    continue
  fi

  case $i in
  'folder1')
    mkdir -p "$SCANDISK_MOUNT/$i"/{subf1,subf2,subf3}
  ;;
  'folder2')
    mkdir -p "$SCANDISK_MOUNT/$i"/{subf4,subf5,subf6}
  ;;
  esac
done

mkdir -p "$SCAN_MOUNT"/{fold1,fold2,fold3}
mkdir -p "$SCANDISK_MOUNT"/{downloads}

chown -R www-data "$SCANDISK_MOUNT" "$SCAN_MOUNT"
```

from the above script, I would expect the following directory structure to be created:

```
.
└── /var/
    ├── /scanserver/
    │   ├── /folder1/
    │   │   ├── /subf1
    │   │   ├── /subf2
    │   │   └── /subf3
    │   ├── /folder2
    │   ├── /folder3
    │   ├── /folder4
    │   └── /downloads
    └── /scan/
        ├── /fold1
        ├── /fold2
        └── /fold3
```

But I am getting this instead and I am not sure what I am missing:

```
.
└── /var/
    ├── /scanserver/
    │   ├── /folder1/
    │   │   └── {subf1,subf2,subf3}
    │   ├── /folder2
    │   ├── /folder3
    │   └── /folder4
    └── /scan/
        └── {fold1,fold2,fold3}
```

As you can see the directories inside `folder1` and `scan` did not expand and the `downloads` directory under `scanserver` was not created either, why?

Comment: You’re most likely using something that whatever `sh` inside the container does not support.

Comment: @DanielB if that is the case how do you explain the first directory structure is created properly? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ however I am not an expert which is why I am asking for some help from others with more experience on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sh` in Alpine doesn't support expanding braces like that.

```
$ docker pull alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:51b67269f354137895d43f3b3d810bfacd3945438e94dc5ac55fdac340352f48
Status: Image is up to date for alpine:latest
docker.io/library/alpine:latest
$ docker run --rm -it alpine:latest sh
/ # echo hello-{1,2,3}
hello-{1,2,3}
```

I'm fairly certain that "*brace expansion*" is a feature in the larger shells, like [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

You could always just use another loop, or use bash:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine:latest sh
/ # apk add bash
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(2/4) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
(3/4) Installing readline (8.2.1-r2)
(4/4) Installing bash (5.2.21-r0)
Executing bash-5.2.21-r0.post-install
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
OK: 10 MiB in 19 packages
/ # bash
c97330de8f43:/# echo hello-{1,2,3}
hello-1 hello-2 hello-3
```

---

> if that is the case how do you explain the first directory structure is created properly?

I'd suggest that whatever system you're running the script on, has `/bin/sh` as a symlink to a bigger shell, like `bash`...